# Can I somehow search few words at the same time(alternative) in Foxit Reader or Adobe Reader?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, foxit-reader

Can I search in FoxIt Reader or Adobe Reader several words at the same time.
By that I mean can I use logical alternative in any of these readers like : `ABC | DEF` or `ABC OR DEF`?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple word search may not be exactly done the way you have shown in your example. But try to accomplish the search using "Advanced Search Options".

To enable "Advanced Search Options" option in pdf reader, go to Edit tab > Preferences > Search > enable "Always show more options in Advance Search"

[image]

Now, press Ctrl+Shift+K to open advanced search option > use "Match Any Of The Words". So that you can enter multiple words in the text box and search it. Hope this helps.

[image]